# Only Vertices move

Tags: mesh, vertices

I am new to blender, I was checking out the features in it and accidentally done something. Now the vertices only move, not the whole model.

[image]

[image]

Kindly help me in bringing back to the old settings.

Regards,
Koushik

Comment: Kindly help me in resolving this issue, I terribly need this going on. Any help would be very useful. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to select all and ctrl+v remove doubles?

Comment: @j.O : Thanks... No, tried that too.. dint work. Still the skeleton only moves not the whole part..

Answer (score 1):

You are in edit mode, press <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch back to object mode then select the object and hit <kbd>G</kbd> to move the object as a whole.

Comment: I don't think this offers any explanation as to *why* they are seeing what they are seeing or why changing to object mode is the answer.

Comment: In object mode I can't edit the model. In Edit mode am facing this issue, So changing it to object mode wont help. Any other suggestions??

Comment: @Koushikpranatharthiharan answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

If your in edit mode press "A" to select everything if your in object mode it should select everything but you can press "G" to grab in object mode ps pressing "tab" key will switch back and forth between object and edit mode.